# Best way to read programming/technical/math PDFs on Android device

Tags: pdf, ebook-reader

I have a ton of programming/technical/math PDFs that I would like to read on my Samsung Epic 4G. I have tried Adobe's PDF reader and ThinkFree office and the reading views destroy the code snippets and images. Zooming in and out is difficult and cumbersome. I have tried converting to ePub and reading using Aldiko but I have the same problem. (Aldiko being the best application I have found for reading on Android).

What solution would you suggest for reading these books on my phone?

I have no problem with converting or buying an application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's also [Documents to Go](http://www.dataviz.com/products/documentstogo/android/) which is a suite - allows for viewing / editing of MS Office docs. PDF support as well. No conversion needed.

An additional plus point is that the paid version integrates with Google Docs online allowing a user to view and edit your files from your Google Docs account directly in Docs To Go. Any changes you make can be saved and synchronized back to Google Docs so that you'll always have the most up-to-date version. You can even create new files in Docs To Go and upload them immediately to your account.

Answer (score 12):

You could try [Picsel Smart Office](http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/productivity/picsel-smart-office_ihgx.html). It handles PDFs natively, and zooming is quite easy.

Disclosure: I work for Picsel.

Comment: I will certainly give this a try.

Comment: Is Smart Office available on the Amazon Appstore for the Kindle Fire?