# What is the best way to read PDFs on Android?

Tags: ebook-reader, pdf

What is the best way to convert PDF's to some kind of format that is easily readable? For example can you convert it to ebook format?

Comment: Related questions: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2188/best-way-to-read-programming-technical-math-pdfs-on-android-device http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2736/is-there-an-app-which-supports-both-pdf-and-epub-ebook-formats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [epub2go.com](http://www.epub2go.com/Web/Convert/GetPdfFromUser.aspx) to convert the pdfs to epub format then used Aldiko to read them.

Comment: Such conversions aren't reliable..

Answer (score 4):

PDFs **are** easily readable, in my books.  Adobe's [Reader app](http://blogs.adobe.com/adobereader/2010/05/introducing_adobe_reader_for_a.html) is actually pretty good, not bloated like the desktop version.

As for conversion, Google probably does a better job of giving you info that I could.  The first result for [this search](http://www.google.ca/search?q=convert+pdf+to+ebook) is a site that will convert to the ePub format, for example.

Adobe Reader for Android:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I didn't like how Adobe's reader tried to make the pdf's readable on a smaller screen.

Comment: @aboes81: you can disable the "Text Reflow" feature, press "Menu > View Mode".

Comment: Can't find the "goto page" function? It baffled me too, almost junked the product.. but there is a way: tap the bottom of a PDF page, it will bring a slider up which you can use to navigate pages - yes.. stupid I know.. why not just include it in the menu?!

Comment: Reader doesn't save your place in the book, does it?  That's the most basic thing you need in an ebook reader.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a PC, try the **[Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) program**. I **converts almost every kind of ebook into every other format of ebook**.

So you can convert any pdf into any format our Android device can read in whatever program you have or are accustomed with.

Best of all, it's free !

The pdf reader from Adobe is a big program to install on the phone ... and aside from that: I don't like the attitude of Adobe to install updates every day ( mind you that's on the pc, but still - we are not living into an Android only world, are we ? ).

Comment: You don't like it when software manufacturers keep their products free of bugs and vulnerabilities? o_O

Comment: @endolith Do you really think Adobe finds vulnerabilities every day ? They just change some algorithm so that a group of hackers has to hack it again every time (this is told to me by a person who programs quicker in assembler than in a high level language - so someone who knows how to disassemble code).