# Is there a PDF (or epub) reader that allows to take notes (or at least to copy text)?

Tags: pdf, ebook-reader, notes, epub

I have many PDFs that I would like to read on my Galaxy Tab and then take notes. Preferably the notes would be attached to the document (may be like [Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/) does), but as a workaround I can also imagine to copy a relevant piece of text into a separate note taking application.

Preferably the reader should handle PDFs directly, but if there is no PDF solution I might also start converting the documents (maybe with [Calibre](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3751/best-way-to-read-pdfs-on-android/3767#3767)) for an epub reader.

I tried Adobe Reader, ThinkFree Office and Aldiko, all of which have acceptable performance loading the PDFs, but aside from [cumbersome zooming](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2188/best-way-to-read-programming-technical-math-pdfs-on-android-device) they also lack the ability to copy or adding notes.

Comment: See also [my answer here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/41540/16575) on a similar question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[RepliGo Reader](http://www.appbrain.com/app/repligo-reader/com.cerience.reader.app)** ($5) allows you to copy text and to make annotations.

Also, if you convert them to epubs the **[Nook](http://www.appbrain.com/app/nook-for-android-by-b-n/bn.ereader)** app allows you to make notes.  It may let you copy text on a non-DRM'd book but I don't have any of those so I'm not able to test it.  (Just note that while the Nook lets you read PDFs the Nook app currently doesnt.

Comment: The RepliGo reader is great, it even allows to draw. What it doesn't support is to add bookmarks (probably external to the PDF). Usually you just can add a note instead of a bookmark, but for protected PDFs the only thing you can do is copy text.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you like the app.  It's too bad that it can't create bookmarks or store notes external to the PDF inside the RepliGo app.

Answer (score 3):

[ezPDF](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=udk.android.reader) does bookmarking, multicolor highlighting, has an annotation list, and many more things. It saves to PDF and you can open the saved file later in Skim.

Answer (score 1):

FBReader or CoolReader do read epubs, and you can select text/make bookmarks there.

Answer (score 0):

The Kindle app allows you to highlight and make notes on both books from the Amazon store, and other files like DRm free .Mobi and Txt files, if you copy them into the Kindle folder on the SD card.

These notes won't sync to the web or to other devices, but are stored with that book on your phone, and you can search through the book for your notes and highlights and see them later.